# Adjusting the querystring/URL in Node's request module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, http-get

I am using the npm request module to make a request within an Express.js application to an internal API. I am passing the following options to the `request` function:

```
requestOptions = {
 url : http://whatever.com/locations/
 method : "GET",
 json : {},
 qs : {
  lng : longitude,
  lat : latitude + '/predictions'
 }
```

The latitude and longitude parameters will change depending on user input and so can not be hard coded.

An example of a URL I wish to make the request to is `http://whatever.com/locations/37.891726,-122.277858/predictions`.

Unfortunately, the result of `request(requestOptions, callback)` is that the request is made to `http://whatever.com/locations/?lng=37.891726&lat=-122.277858%2Fpredictions`.

I know from the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) that I can adjust the separator from `&` to `,`, and also that the `/` I manually appended to `lat` can be properly sent if I add the attribute `qsStringifyOptions : {encode: false}` to `requestOptions`. But appending `/predictions` manually the way I did feels wrong to begin with, and I still have the difficulty of the remaining format -- namely, removing the `lat=`/`lng=`, the initial ? from the query string.

Is it possible to somehow change the querystring options to suit my needs, or is it possible that the request package is not what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if http://whatever.com/locations/[lng],[lat]/predictions is what you want then lng & lat are not querystring parameters, but part of the URI path. You can skip the querystring entirely and change your requestOptions to:

```
requestOptions = {
    url: 'http://whatever.com/locations/' + lng + ',' + lat + '/predictions',
    method: 'GET',
    json: {}
};
```

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear in my post -- I'll edit that now. This is a component of a controller where lat and lng are requests that will change so I can not hard code the URL.

Comment: The url doesn't have to be hardcoded, but the point is that the values should be in the url. Edited the post to use lng & lat variables instead.

Comment: Thanks!! I'm new so I can't upvote but that did it for me. No idea why that didn't occur to me to begin with.